# React Native: "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews.." warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, user-interface, scrollview

I am having an issue with my `<ScrollView>` and the `<GooglePlacesAutocomplete>` components.

[Link to GIF of the current issue](https://gfycat.com/plainmalecatbird)

After watching the short GIF you might notice that I am getting a warning:

> VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation - use another VirtualizedList-backed container instead.

Also, when I try to click on Dallas, TX, USA nothing happens. 
If I were to delete the `<ScrollView>` component then when I click on a place, it takes it without any issues.

Here is my code:

```
    import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete'; 

    [...] //code removed from brevity

    return(
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.fullPage}>   
    <ScrollView
     stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} >
        <Header/> 
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text>Search for fun near you</Text>

            <View style = {styles.firstLine}>
                <Text>On </Text>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatepicker}><MaterialCommunityIcons name="alarm" color={'orange'} size={25} spin={true} /></TouchableOpacity>
                    {show && (
                    <DateTimePicker
                        testID="dateTimePicker"
                        timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={0}
                        value={date}
                        mode={mode}
                        display="default"
                        onChange={onChange}
                    />)}

            </View>
                <Text style={styles.txt}>Date: {date.toDateString()}</Text>
            <View style = {styles.secondLine}>
                <Text>Within </Text>
                <ModalDropdown 
                    defaultValue='Pick a mile' options={["5", '10','20','50', '75']}
                    onSelect= {(index,value)=>{
                        setMiles(value);
                    }}
                    style = {styles.mileageDropdown}>  
                </ModalDropdown>
                <Text> miles of </Text>

            </View>

            <View style = {styles.thirdLine}>
            <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
                         placeholder='Insert place to find'
                         minLength={2}
                         keyboardAppearance={'light'}
                         fetchDetails={false} 
                         onPress={(data, details = null) => { // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
                             {setPlace(data.description)}
                            }}                 
                            styles={{
                            textInputContainer: {
                                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                                borderTopWidth: 0,
                                borderBottomWidth:0,
                                width: '100%',
                                },
                             textInput: {
                                fontSize: 16
                                },
                            }}

                            query={{
                                key: 'SomeAPIkey',
                                language: 'en', // language of the results
                              }}
                        />
            </View>      

            <View style={styles.btn}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress} style={styles.btnSearch}><Text style={styles.txtbtn}>Search</Text></TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            </View>




            {arr.map((item, key)=>(  
                <Card key={key}>                
                         <View style={styles.cardFirstLine}><Text>{item.user}</Text><Text style={{marginLeft:40}}>{item.location}</Text></View>
                         <View><Text>{item.datePosted}</Text></View>
                         <View style={styles.cardImage}></View>
                         <View><Text>{item.description}</Text></View>
                         <View><Text>{item.eventDate}</Text></View>
                         <View><Text>{item.comments}</Text></View>         
                </Card>
                ))}

     </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)}              

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            fullPage:{
                flex:1,
            },
            container:{
                paddingTop:65,
                margin: 10,
                alignItems: 'center'
            },
            firstLine:{
                flexDirection: "row",
                alignContent: "center",
                padding: 10,
                alignItems : 'center'
            },
            secondLine:{
                flexDirection: "row",
                padding: 10,
                alignItems : 'center'
            },
            thirdLine:{
                flexDirection: "row",
                padding: 10,
                alignItems : 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
            },
            datepicker:{
                paddingLeft:10,
                paddingTop:5
            },
            mileageDropdown:{
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                padding:5,
                paddingTop:5
            },
            btn:{
                paddingTop:10
            },
            btnSearch:{ 
                backgroundColor: 'purple',
                padding:20,
                margin:20,
                width: 100,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                borderRadius : 5,
            },
            txtbtn:{
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: 14,
                color: 'orange'
            },
            place:{
                marginTop: 30,
                padding: 10,
                borderColor: "red",
                borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth
            },
            displayImage:{
                width:200,
                height:200,
                padding:40,
                borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                borderColor: "red",
            },  
            txt:{
                borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                borderColor: 'black',

            },
            cardFirstLine:{
                padding: 5,
                flexDirection:'row',
            },
            cardImage:{
                paddingTop: 15,
                borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
                borderColor: 'black',
                width: '75%',
                height:100,

            }
        });
```

I did review most of the StackOverflow posts regarding this, but I have not been able to solve the issue on my end. 
Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with this UI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are receiving this warning because `react-native-google-places-autocomplete` renders a `<FlatList />` component to show results, and you have `<GooglePlacesAutoComplete />` wrapped in a `<ScrollView />`.

> Also, when I try to click on Dallas, TX, USA nothing happens.
>   If I were to delete the  component then when I click on a place, it takes it without any issues.

This is a common issue, try adding `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` or `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'` to your `<ScrollView />`.

Comment: That works great! I still get the warning though, would you happen to know how to get rid of that?

Comment: I believe you will see the warning as long you use the ScrollView.  It's a warning, not an error. If it works for you, leave it as is.

Comment: Don't listen to @StevenBell, worst advice, if it has a warning you're doing something wrong, do it the right way. In this case it's a performance risk, if you have a long list your user's device will slow down, eat more battery and possibly crash.

Comment: @CaioMar then how do you fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't recall how I did it. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Set disableScroll to false in GooglePlacesAutocomplete props.

```
<ScrollView>
    <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
        placeholder="Type a place"
        query={{
            key: KEY,
        }}
        fetchDetails={true}
        disableScroll={true}
    />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by replacing ScrollView with SectionList.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionlist